# awk: "not enough arguments to satisfy format string" error in script

Tags: shell, awk, printf

I created a script to grab the data from our Unix server, however I am getting the below error:

```
awk: cmd. line:8: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `|%-17s|%-16s|%-15s|'
                     ^ ran out for this one
```

Below is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export TERM=xterm
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile="$(date '+/var/EndpointUsage_%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y.csv')"
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "|-----------------|------------------|------------------|";
printf "|%-18s|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n","Registration ID", "Port", "Ongoing Calls"
}
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Port/ { port = $3 ; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "|-------------------|-----------------|------------- -----|";
printf "|%-18s|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,port,$3 }
END{
print "|------------------|------------------|------------------|";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

Can anyone please help me on this, how can I resolve this error?

**AFTER CHANGES** the columns are showing correctly, but the `Port` column does not have any data.  It should have 0 or if other endpoint have 1 o 2 Port number.

```
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|Registration ID   |Port             |Ongoing Calls   |
|-------------------|-----------------|------------------|
|-------------------|-----------------|------------------
|CC_XXXXXX_01_0     |                 |174             |
|-------------------|-----------------|------------------|
```

Comment: You asked a question, you got [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192985/1745001). Now you've hit your next problem you've changed your question to the point where it makes no sense in relation to your original question and associated answer and are now asking for help with this completely different, new problem. Don't do that. Put this question back to how it started, mark the answer you got as accepted and post a new question if you have to but try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: I agree with @EdMorton.  It is actually better to ask a different question, linking to this one, so that future readers will be able to benefit from specific answers to specific questions.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more useful tips.  Also, in your new question, please show the input file, the code, the output you get, and the output you expect --- that way you'll get higher-quality answers more quickly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The offending `printf` is:

```
printf "|%-18s|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3
                                      ^^^^ awk wants to see a third parameter here
```

You have three `%s` sequences in the format string, so `awk` expects `,<something else>` after the `$3`.  I think maybe it's a copy and paste error.  Since you are only printing two column headers, try removing the `%-16s|` at the end and seeing if that gives you the output you expect.

**Edit** Without seeing your input file, I don't know for sure.  Try this, though -

```
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Port/ { port = $3 ; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "|-------------------|-----------------|------------------|";
printf "|%-18s|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,port,$3 }
```

I added `{port=$3;next}` to save the port number, and then when you print them out, I changed `id,$3` to `id,port,$3` to print the saved `id`, saved `port`, and ongoing-calls value (`$3`) in order.

Comment: @EdMorton hi, i am sorry..i am pretty new in this, i did not get that concern, i am just trying to learn it and would like to know where is my mistake in above script.

Comment: @cxw Thanks a lot for your reply, I think i missed the third row, when i pasted, actually i want 3 row, one is for Registration ID, Port and Ongoing calls, i updated the script as well.

Comment: @EdMorton hi Morton, thanks a lot for your help, i am sorry i did not get the answer cxw mentioned, can you please edit the script i mentioned, so that i know where is the mistake and what changes you did? That will be very big favor of yours?, BTW yes it was Column... Thank you again

Comment: @LiveCom Edited

Comment: thanks again..i know now, where i was wrong, but you know for the "port" field its not taking any data, i updated the script above..you can see

Comment: @EdMorton Sure, yes since i am learning, and i am currently learning from programming Bible and some online links